# File Upload is not uploading in React Native iOS, Same is working in android platform

Tags: ios, react-native, file, uploading

I am try to upload the document, file from react native app. The api is working fine in Android platform but in iOS, I am not able to upload the same. I am using apisauce version ^2.0.0, the strange thing I am not getting any error. Server did not get the request.

Following is the form data:
`{ "_parts": [ [ "attachment", { "uri": "file:///Users/yogeshchauhan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3BCF94FF-0E3E-41E4-B1D5-700E1F85BF4F/data/Containers/Data/Application/9E8CB982-DB6F-439F-BFB8-0DB341E15768/Library/Caches/ImageManipulator/0D8DAD55-4658-4132-A118-12F2302ACF93.jpg", "type": "image/jpeg", "name": "C23BD088-411F-4C4A-A6B0-82DB9945D49A.jpg" } ] ] }`

I am using the following version of react:
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.0"

Answer (score 1):

In iOS you have to remove `file://` from the uri, pass image path without file://.  For example on file select set selected image in one of your state variable for example call it `selectedImage`. And when you pass on image replace `file://` with  blank string based on device like this :

```js
  const datas = new FormData();

  datas.append('images', {
    name: selectedImage.fileName,
    type: selectedImage.type,
    uri:
      Platform.OS === 'android' ? selectedImage.uri : selectedImage.uri.replace('file://', ''),
  });
```

Comment: my formData is as following:
`{
  "_parts": [
    [
      "attachment",
      {
        "uri": "/Users/yogeshchauhan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3BCF94FF-0E3E-41E4-B1D5-700E1F85BF4F/data/Containers/Data/Application/9E8CB982-DB6F-439F-BFB8-0DB341E15768/Library/Caches/ImageManipulator/12D07910-71BC-4341-83DD-436C489197A5.jpg",
        "type": "image/jpeg",
        "name": "7A08AAD4-F543-4988-A43E-2196F5A699B9.jpg"
      }
    ]
  ]
}` 

Still api did not trigger and is not throwing error too. Feeling very helpless :(

Comment: Are you passing this whole object ? Can you please tell me what error you are getting ?

Comment: @KishanBharda for android is not working. `const formData = new FormData();
        const uri = Platform.OS === 'android' ? upload[0].uri : upload[0].uri.replace('file://', '');
        formData.append('upload', {
            uri,
            name: upload[0].name,
            type: upload[0].type,
        });`

Comment: @KishanBharda i am using Document picker it working fine in IOS but not working in android my re quest is `{"_parts": [["upload", [Object]], ["am_accountNo", "967726"], ["ci_id", "C967726"], ["doc_type", "CS_Demand_1"], ["p_code", "PPL"], ["tp_code", "EMAILCAMPAIGNV1"], ["description", "Drr"], ["remarks", "Vff"], ["others", ""]]}`